# Java EAR - Class Path and Libraries

Tags: java, classpath, ear

I have a java ear archive, which containts "lib" folder, declared as library directory in the application.xml.

My problem is that some of the jars inside lib folder are not needed by some modules. furthermore, one of my modules (a .war archive) contains in its own lib folder a library which is older compared to the one inside the .ear. This causes a clash between the two libraries.

I want that my module gets in its classpath only the libraries defined in its own lib folder. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on which app server you are using for deployment - you can create custom classloader hierarchy within weblogic
more here -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG295

for websphere - you can use PARENT_LAST attribute in the deployment.xml  to control this hierarchy to an extent.